# Input field is not updated

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

This is the complete source code: http://www.sendspace.com/file/lwxpyf

I have a problem with a JSF page which I can't solve. I have a JSF page which is used to store application settings into database table.
This is the source code of the JSF page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="NVIDIA.com" /> Settings Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1180px; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>

        </div>  

        <div id="greenBand" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-allh" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Application Settings"  style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"  value="resources/images/logo_application_settings.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">
                <h:form>
                    <div id="settingsdiv" style="width:550px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:r; top:20px; left:1px">

                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <h:panelGroup>User Session Timeout</h:panelGroup>
                            <h:panelGroup>
                                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{ApplicationController.settings['SessionTTL']}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{ApplicationController.settings['SessionTTL']}" itemLabel="#{ApplicationController.settings['SessionTTL']}" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="two" itemLabel="Option two" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="three" itemLabel="Option three" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="custom" itemLabel="Define custom value" />
                                    <f:ajax render="input" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>&nbsp;
                                <h:panelGroup id="input">
                                    <h:inputText value="#{ApplicationController.settings['SessionTTL']}" rendered="#{ApplicationController.settings['SessionTTL'] == 'custom'}" required="true" />
                                </h:panelGroup>          
                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <h:panelGroup>Maximum allowed users</h:panelGroup>
                            <h:panelGroup>
                                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{ApplicationController.settings['MaxUsersActive']}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{ApplicationController.settings['MaxUsersActive']}" itemLabel="#{ApplicationController.settings['MaxUsersActive']}" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="two" itemLabel="Option two" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="three" itemLabel="Option three" />
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="custom" itemLabel="Define custom value" />
                                    <f:ajax render="inputl" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>&nbsp;
                                <h:panelGroup id="inputl">
                                    <h:inputText value="#{ApplicationController.settings['MaxUsersActive']}" rendered="#{ApplicationController.settings['MaxUsersActive'] == 'custom'}" required="true" />
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </h:panelGroup>                                                                     
                        </h:panelGrid>                         



                    </div>   

                    <div id="settingsonediv" style="width:350px; height:400px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:20px; left:400px">



                    </div>   

                    <div id="settingstwodiv" style="width:150px; height:60px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:380px; left:800px">

                        <h:commandButton value="Save Settings" action="#{ApplicationController.updateDBSettings}">
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                        </h:commandButton>

                    </div>   


                </h:form> 
            </div>  
        </div>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

And this is the managed bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
// or import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
/* include SQL Packages */
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
// or import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;   

import org.glassfish.osgicdi.OSGiService;

@Named("ApplicationController")
@SessionScoped
public class Application implements Serializable {

    /* This Hash Map will be used to store setting and value */
    private HashMap<String, String> settingsMap = null;    

    public Application(){     
    }   

    /* Call the Oracle JDBC Connection driver */
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/Oracle")
    private DataSource ds;


    /* Hash Map
     * Send this hash map with the settings and values to the JSF page
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getsettings(){
        return settingsMap;        
    }

    /* Get a Hash Map with settings and values. The table is genarated right 
     * after the constructor is initialized. 
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void initSettings() throws SQLException
    {        
        settingsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        if(ds == null) {
                throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");
        }
        /* Initialize a connection to Oracle */
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection(); 

        if(conn == null) {
                throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");
        }
        /* With SQL statement get all settings and values */
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * from GLOBALSETTINGS");

        try
        {
            //get data from database        
            ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
            while (result.next())
            {
               settingsMap.put(result.getString("SettingName"), result.getString("SettingValue"));
            }            
        }
        finally
        {
            ps.close();
            conn.close();         
        }        
    }

    /* JSF returns the updated values into the HashMap */

    /* Update Settings Values */
    public void updateDBSettings() throws SQLException {

            String SQL_Statement = null;

            if (ds == null) throw new SQLException();      
        Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
            if (conn == null) throw new SQLException();      

    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        boolean committed = false;
            try {  
                   /* Insert the new settings values with one SQL statement */
                   SQL_Statement = "UPDATE GLOBALSETTINGS " +
                                        "SET \"SettingValue\" = " +
                                          "CASE " +
                                            "WHEN \"SettingName\" = 'SessionTTL' THEN ? " +
                                            "WHEN \"SettingName\" = 'MaxUsersActive' THEN ? " +
                                          "END " +
                                   "WHERE \"SettingName\"  IN ('SessionTTL', 'MaxUsersActive')";
                   /* Exete thre SQL statement */
                   PreparedStatement updateQuery = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_Statement);
                   updateQuery.setString(1, settingsMap.get("SessionTTL"));
                   updateQuery.setString(2, settingsMap.get("MaxUsersActive"));

                   updateQuery.executeQuery();                                                         
                   conn.commit();
                   committed = true;
               } finally {
                   if (!committed) conn.rollback();
                   }
            }
            finally {
            /* Release the resource after all SQL queries are executed */
            conn.close();                
            }             
            /* Refresh Hash Map
             * Get again settings from Oracle
             */
           initSettings();

     }    


}
```

This is the problem that I face:

When I open the JSF page I get this menus:

[image]

Then I select custom from the menu:

[image]

I get this input field next to the menu:

[image]

Then I enter custom value from the keyboard:

[image]

But when I click Save button I get this. I can see that the database field is updated but the values is "custom"

[image]

When I enter the same twice value I get this:

[image]

I seems that when I click `custom` and I enter the custom value the HashMap is not updated. It's strange that when I do it again the HashMap is updated and the value is correct. How I can fix this problem?

Best Wishes

***EDIT***

I suspect that the JSF version causes this problem. This is the content of the `faces-config.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
       version="2.0">
        <managed-bean>
            <description>comment</description>
            <managed-bean-name>ApplicationController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.DX_57.SM_57.Application</managed-bean-class>    
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>        
        </managed-bean>
        <managed-bean>
            <description>comment</description>
            <managed-bean-name>DashboardController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.DX_57.SM_57.Dashboard</managed-bean-class>    
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>        
        </managed-bean>
        <managed-bean>
            <description>comment</description>
            <managed-bean-name>DatabaseController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.DX_57.SM_57.Database</managed-bean-class>    
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>        
        </managed-bean>
        <managed-bean>
            <description>comment</description>
            <managed-bean-name>GeneralController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.DX_57.SM_57.General</managed-bean-class>    
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>        
        </managed-bean>
        <managed-bean>
            <description>comment</description>
            <managed-bean-name>GlassfishController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.DX_57.SM_57.Glassfish</managed-bean-class>    
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>        
        </managed-bean>
        <managed-bean>
            <description>comment</description>
            <managed-bean-name>LinuxController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.DX_57.SM_57.Linux</managed-bean-class>    
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>        
        </managed-bean>
        <managed-bean>
            <description>comment</description>
            <managed-bean-name>LinuxConfigurationController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.DX_57.SM_57.LinuxConfiguration</managed-bean-class>    
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>        
        </managed-bean>
        <managed-bean>
            <description>comment</description>
            <managed-bean-name>LogController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.DX_57.SM_57.Log</managed-bean-class>    
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>        
        </managed-bean>    
        <managed-bean>
            <description>comment</description>
            <managed-bean-name>OracleController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.DX_57.SM_57.Oracle</managed-bean-class>    
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>        
        </managed-bean>
        <managed-bean>
            <description>comment</description>
            <managed-bean-name>UpdatesController</managed-bean-name>
            <managed-bean-class>com.DX_57.SM_57.Updates</managed-bean-class>    
            <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>        
        </managed-bean>   
    </faces-config>
```

This is the content of `beans.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

This is the content of `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

How they should be changed in order to use the latest JSF version?

**EDIT 2** I disabled JavaScript in Firefox. I tested the code. It turns out that it works but I have to click Save button every time:

[image]

I choose custom and click Save Button

[image]

[image]

When I click the Save button the custom field appears.

[image]

When I enter the custom value and click Save button the field is updated.

I suppose that it won't work because the data is not send back from the JavaScrips to the server

**EDIT 3** Debug information from firebug:

I choose from the menu custom:

```
<update id="j_idt5:input"><![CDATA[<span id="j_idt5:input"><input type="text" name="j_idt5:j_idt15" value="custom" /></span>]]></update>
```

I type custom value:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="j_idt5"><![CDATA[
<form id="j_idt5" name="j_idt5" method="post" action="/SM_57-1.0-SNAPSHOT/Application.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_idt5" value="j_idt5" />
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>User Session Timeout</td>
<td><select id="j_idt5:j_idt10" name="j_idt5:j_idt10" size="1" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'j_idt5:input')">    <option value="custom" selected="selected">custom</option>
    <option value="two">Option two</option>
    <option value="three">Option three</option>
    <option value="custom" selected="selected">Define custom value</option>
</select><span id="j_idt5:input"><input type="text" name="j_idt5:j_idt15" value="custom" /></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Maximum allowed users</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input id="j_idt5:j_idt18" type="submit" name="j_idt5:j_idt18" value="Save Settings" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','@form','@form');return false" />
</form>]]></update><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[-8356663926661541536:7758149566419150570]]></update></changes></partial-response>
```

I click save button:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="j_idt5"><![CDATA[
<form id="j_idt5" name="j_idt5" method="post" action="/SM_57-1.0-SNAPSHOT/Application.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_idt5" value="j_idt5" />
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>User Session Timeout</td>
<td><select id="j_idt5:j_idt10" name="j_idt5:j_idt10" size="1" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'j_idt5:input')">    <option value="wdwdew" selected="selected">wdwdew</option>
    <option value="two">Option two</option>
    <option value="three">Option three</option>
    <option value="custom">Define custom value</option>
</select><span id="j_idt5:input"></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Maximum allowed users</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input id="j_idt5:j_idt18" type="submit" name="j_idt5:j_idt18" value="Save Settings" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','@form','@form');return false" />
</form>]]></update><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[-8356663926661541536:7758149566419150570]]></update></changes></partial-response>
```

Comment: Ok, would both of you be so kind as to register your SO accounts and name then? People are flagging your questions as potential duplicates/sock puppets, and naming the accounts would at least make it less likely that people do that.

Comment: try adding `f:ajax` so that your data inside the form will be submitted to server

replace your save btn with this

    <h:commandButton value="Save Settings" action="#{applicationController.updateDBSettings}">
        <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
    </:commandButton>

Comment: JSF ought to be browser independent. Which JSF impl/version are you using? Are you using any addidtional JavaScripts? Remove/disable them all just for testing.

Comment: I use Netbeans to create JSF pages. I don't know which version I use but looking at the faces-config.xml I see that I use JSF 2.0. I suppose that in faces-config.xml I must set the JSF version? I use JQuery into the JSF. I will test the code without the JQuery.

Comment: Check the server logs. The JSF impl/version is logged there.

Comment: This is the log file: http://pastebin.com/NsrxgFKQ I think that the version is Mojarra 2.1.6

Comment: PS. The code is NOT working on Chrome

Comment: I tested a simple mockup page with 2.1.6 and it works for me across all browsers. I think it's caused by the additional JavaScripts which you still didn't tell anything about.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9140/discussion-between-peter-penzov-and-balusc)

Comment: As far as I know I only use css. Here is the complete source code:  http://www.sendspace.com/file/lwxpyf  The name of the JSF page in which I test the input field is Application

Comment: Note that when you disable JavaScript at browser level instead of removing the additional JavaScripts, then JSF `<f:ajax>` will not work  (ajax is sending HTTP requests by JavaScript, you know?). I did **not** want to suggest to disable JavaScript at browser level. I wanted to suggest to remove/disable all those additional JavaScript files which you've possibly in `<script>` or `<h:outputScript>` elements. If it works, then the problem is caused by one of them. Reading Chrome/Firebug JavaScript console for any error/exception logs should also give insights.

Comment: @BalusC if you want I can give you access to the server to test the JSF with Firebug? I tested a plain JSF with only a menu, input field and button without any other script but the problem is still there.

Comment: Not now. I've other (paid) things to do.

Comment: @BalusC it seems that this problem cannot be solved. How I can get write the code and get the same result? Maybe instead of using  HashMap I can return to getter/setter to display the data into the JSF page? What are the options?

Comment: The problem is not in the code posted so far. I can't reproduce it on a blank playground project. Daniel (one of the answerers) apparently also not. All I can guess is that you've a JavaScript conflict somewhere.

Comment: I removed all the code of the JSF page leading only the form and the save button. But the result is the same. I will try to reproduce the code with just a clean JSF page and the bean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've redefinied the beans in `faces-config.xml`. Your managed bean is been redefinied as a request scoped one:

```xml
<managed-bean>
    <description>comment</description>
    <managed-bean-name>ApplicationController</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.DX_57.SM_57.Application</managed-bean-class>    
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>        
</managed-bean>
```

The managed bean configurations in `faces-config.xml` file have **precedence** over the annotations. Your `ApplicationController` bean is in reality thus a request scoped JSF managed bean, not a session scoped CDI managed bean like as you have declared by annotations. On every single ajax request a brand new one will be created. All changes done in previous requests are "forgotten".

You have 2 options:

- Remove the bean configuration from `faces-config.xml`.
- Change the managed bean scope to `view` (please note that it will then still be JSF who is managing the bean instance, not CDI and that CDI doesn't have a suitable `@ViewScoped` annotation).

Comment: Option 1 don't work. I removed the configuration of the bean from faces-config.xml but then when I open the JSF page nothing happens - when I click the button save nothing happens. Something is missing. Option 2 works. Do you know why when I remove the configuration of the bean faces-config.xml the bean won't work. As far as I know in JSF 2.0 this configuration is not necessary. Thank you for solving the problem!

Comment: Maybe the CDI configuration is broken. You were using CDI annotations instead of JSF annotations to manage the bean. Instead of the `view` scoped bean in `faces-config.xml`, you can also have `@ManagedBean @ViewScoped` on the class.

Comment: As far as I remember I only need to have 'web.xml' file into the WEB-INF directory to activate CDI into the bundle. Do I need something else?

Comment: You need a JSF 2.0 compatible `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml` to get JSF annotations to work. The file does not necessarily need to contain `<managed-bean>` entries. You can remove `<managed-bean>` entries from the file and use `@ManagedBean(name="beanName") @ViewScoped` on all beans instead of `@Named("beanName") @SessionScoped`.

Comment: I deleted the content of faces-config.xml leaving only <faces-config tag and I edited the beans this way: http://pastebin.com/uxe1Ai4C I edited the name of the bean this way: @ManagedBean("ApplicationController") (if I add name Netbeans shows error). I get this error when I run the JSF page: http://pastebin.com/RYV8jUwr

Comment: I think your Glassfish configuration is either messed up or has a peculiar bug, possibly this: http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-15225 Consider opening a new question.

Comment: ok, I will ask in Glassfish forum is there a solution. If not I cannot use CDI.

Comment: One more question: I found that there are three types of beans: JSF Managed beans, CDI beans and EJB. I will need CDI in order to use resources from OSGI bundles. But in order to use CDI beans I need to return the code to this @Named("ApplicationController")
@ViewScoped and I have to write the scope of the beans into faces-config.xml. What are the appropriate settings for CDI beans?

Comment: Once again: you can't mix CDI and JSF annotations on managed beans. `@Named @ViewScoped` is invalid. It would implicitly become a `@Named @RequestScoped` and the `@ViewScoped` would be ignored. CDI doesn't have a concept of "view scope". Use `@ManagedBean @ViewScoped`. Or if you really need CDI, use `@Named @SessionScoped` or `@Named @ConversationScoped` and manage the `Conversation` yourself. As to EJB, that's a completely different story. It should be used for service and DAO classes only, not for managed beans.

Comment: Your concrete problem is that CDI was broken and that JSF managed bean declarations in `faces-config.xml` were been used which is incorrectly been set to `request` scope.

Comment: By the way which web Java Application do you recommend and you use? Which one has less problems like this?

Comment: I've never had problems like that, but I've also never used OSGI. Both CDI and JSF annotations have always worked fine for me without any `faces-config.xml` registration on Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6/7 and Tomcat 7 (with Weld).

Answer (score 2):

try adding `f:ajax` so that your data inside the form will be submitted to server

replace your save btn with this

```
<h:commandButton value="Save Settings" action="#{applicationController.updateDBSettings}">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

in order to see where the problem is: try remove the call to `initSettings()` from the end of updateDBSettings() , or make sure that the re-init does populate teh map with the proper values...

**Edit:**

Open your application in Chrome and click the F12 , in the dev tools click the scripts tab , then right beneath that you can see all the js files that where loaded, do you see any suspicious "library's" over there? try to remove its includes from you wen pages... to see what cause the error in FF

Comment: what's deleting got to do with bounty?

Comment: it works for me... when i enter the updateDBSettings the map hold the value , here : SessionTTL=888 , are you sure you restarted the web server after adding the ajax?

Comment: I use Glassfish. I edited the code and I deployed the compiled code as OSGI bundle.

Comment: remove the call to `initSettings()` from the end of updateDBSettings()

Comment: Ajax or not should not make any difference. Reloading from DB is necessary for the case the map holds outdated values.

Comment: I tried the bought proposals but the result is the same - not working. See the h:selectOneMenu and h:inputText. Do you find anything wrong? Maybe attribute is missing?

Comment: when u enter the method updateDBSettings , do you see the value u have typed instead of the custom string? i copied your code as is without all the DB stuff... and it works just fine

Answer (score -1):

i think you should redefine the

```
<managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
```

use

```
<managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
```

instead

Comment: Bad advice. Read the currently accepted answer for the right advice.