# AJAX pages with CDI beans and @ConversationScoped

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi

I'm interested What is the proper way to use JSF pages with AJAX when I use CDI.
I tested to configure the CDI beans with `@SessionScoped` but I found that there is a problem with AJAX.

Is it proper to use AJAX with CDI beans configured with `@ConversationScoped`?

And I found that I have to put `conversation.begin();` into the Bean constructor and `conversation.end();` into Java method which must be when the session is completed. Can I somehow do this automatically?

P.S Can I use this code to automatically free the resource when the user closes the page?

```
@Remove
public void finishIt(){
     conversation.end();
}
```

Comment: What CDI implementation are you using? Seam or Apache CODI? CODI has the `@ViewAccessScoped` that I quite like. It lives as long one of the jsf pages references it. It's a bit like an automatic conversation

Comment: I use the package `javax.inject.Named`. I suppose that this is part of the standard JSF framework.

Comment: _"... but I found that there is a problem with AJAX."_ What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @MattHandy I described the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9761568/jsf-input-field-is-not-updated

Comment: CODI, SEAM3, DeltaSpike (= merger of CODI, SEAM3 and others) are CDI extensions/add-ons. Esp. CODI and DeltaSpike can be used with Weld and OpenWebBeans (= the real CDI implementations). See e.g. https://builds.apache.org/view/A-F/view/DeltaSpike/ linked in http://incubator.apache.org/deltaspike/build.html

Comment: javax.inject.Named is not part of JSF. It's an own specification. See JSR 330 (http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=330) which is used by CDI (http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=299)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *And I found that I have to put `conversation.begin();` into the Bean constructor and `conversation.end();` into Java method which must be when the session is completed.*

That's correct. See also among others [How to replace @ManagedBean / @ViewScope by CDI in JSF 2.0/2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384369/how-to-replace-managedbean-viewscope-by-cdi/14384824#14384824) for a concrete code example.

> *Can I somehow do this automatically?*

If you want a bean which must live as long as you're postbacking on a single view, then upgrade to at least JSF 2.2. It [provides](https://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/p/jsf-22.html#1087) a CDI compatible [`@ViewScoped`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/faces/view/ViewScoped.html) out the box.

If you however want a bean which must live as long as you reference it in a view, regardless of the view you're sitting in, then consider using [`@ViewAccessScoped`](https://deltaspike.apache.org/javadoc/1.4.1/org/apache/deltaspike/core/api/scope/ViewAccessScoped.html) of [DeltaSpike](https://deltaspike.apache.org/) instead. Once you navigate to a view which doesn't reference the bean anywhere, it will be trashed.

#### See also:

- [How to choose the right bean scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)

Comment: Can I use `@Remove
public void finishIt(){
     conversation.end();
}` to call `conversation.end();` when the JSF is closed. And also when I can expect JSF 2.2 to be ready to testing?

Comment: No. Your statement "the JSF is closed" makes also no sense by the way. JSF 2.2 is currently available as milestone release. See http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html The official release is planned around April 2013, as part of Java EE 7.

Comment: One more interesting question about the problem. Is it planned CODI to replace CDI into the near future? I just want to plan which technology to use.

Comment: CODI does not replace CDI. It is just an extension to CDI. Like as that e.g. PrimeFaces is an extension to JSF.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for the answer! I will wait for the new JSF version.

Comment: It's easy to go with CODI and move to DeltaSpike (= merger of CODI, SEAM and others) as soon as it is ready. We are using both in parallel without issues for large applications.

Answer (score 1):

By default the Conversation object is in transient state. Invocation of the begin method marks it as long-running (when a real conversation starts). Ending conversation (by invoking end method) marks Conversation object as transient.

A transient conversation scoped bean will live for a life cycle of single request .

long-ending conversation(initiated by conversation.begin) will run unless conversation.end is called.